# React Native - Unexpected Identifier 'str' with fresh project

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I installed a fresh react-native projecect on Windows 10 using:

```
npm install -g react-native
react-native init myproject
cd myproject
react-native run-android
```

I have Android Studio installed and I am running a Pixel 2XL emulator with Oreo 8.0.

It successfully compiles

```
react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.pom
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar

> Task :app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_28_x86(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 53s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed
Running D:\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (D:\AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.myproject/com.myproject.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.myproject/.MainActivity }
```

and once it finished it opens up in the emulator and I get

[image: Screenshot of emulator]

With the Metro Bundler saying:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   D:\Workspace\Projects\myproject

Loading dependency graph, done.
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (543/543), done.

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2018:23:13:43 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "okhttp/3.11.0"
```

Any ideas? Googling it finds one thing: https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile/issues/122

This however says it's solved but I'm not seeing the same issue with the error:

```
adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
```

And I have my SDK under `D:\AndroidSDK` so I have `D:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools` already listed under my path system environment variables, so I'm not sure if exporting the path again would do anything. I also have the java sdk installed under `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191` and that is also set up in the environment variables under JAVA_HOME

Here's a list of my environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME 
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
ANDROID_HOME 
    D:\AndroidSDK
PATH
    %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
    %ANDROID_HOME%\tools
    %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin
    %ANDROID_HOME%\emulator
```

Additionally here's my `android/build.gradle`

https://gist.github.com/Snowdrama/d7cc4a0b51d9d331ae75ebd4bf6d7b03

And my `android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties`

https://gist.github.com/Snowdrama/a69bed755fb042da9e9b52c5abb8788d

Mostly because I read somewhere that the gradle version could have issues like this, not sure, but I am providing them anyway.

I'm just confused cause I haven't made any changes yet! Haha!

Hopefully I gave enough info! If any is needed let me know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have ANDROID_HOME set up correctly?

Do you have all of these in your path?

$ANDROID_HOME/tools

$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin

$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

$ANDROID_HOME/emulator

Comment: @NielsLadekarl ANDROID_HOME is set to `D:\AndroidSDK` and my path has all of those, however I haven them set as like `D:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools` and `D:\AndroidSDK\tools` etc. Would it not be %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools Not sure what the $ does instead

Comment: Okay that seems fine then. And yes, sorry. In your case it would be %ANDROID_HOME%. The other is for OSX.

Comment: I noticed that your JAVA_HOME is not pointing to the correct directory though. Should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

Comment: @NielsLadekarl okay I'll remove these: `%JAVA_HOME%\jdk1.8.0_191` or `%JAVA_HOME%\jre1.8.0_191` and then add that and then restart and try it again.

Comment: @NielsLadekarl Unfortunately that did not fix the issue, but I updated the question to reflect the env change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I had this error and fixed it by slowly re-introducing my changes.

1. Backup your work so you don't lose anything
2. Make note of all changes you did leading up to the error (e.g. `git status`)
3. Revert everything back to a working state (e.g. `git checkout src`)
4. Slowly reintroduce changes until you get the exact error you got (other errors are fine, keep going one-by-one).

Turned out to be something seemingly innocuous and benign for me. I had to change:

```
for (const key of keys) {
    const obj = body[key]
```

to:

```js
for (let key of keys) {
    let obj = body[key]
```

Edit:

I stored the broken version of my app in a separate folder and could reliably reproduce / fix the bug. However, after rebooting the computer, I can no longer reproduce the bug.

This tells me it has *something* to do with cached files. If you still struggle, try:

- `watchman watch-del-all`
- `yarn cache clear` or `npm cache clean`
- `rm -rf node_modules`
- reboot computer

Comment: Yeah not sure what happened but the last step fixed it just delete node_modules and then just reinstall with `npm i`

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading via react-native git command line tool `react-native-git-upgrade` as described here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading

I was having this issue with same errors on essentially a new project on a pixel 2 simulator running Oreo 8.1, and upgrading my `react-native` cli seemed to fix it.

I was running my project based off react native 0.57.0 and had been upgrading the patch releases just by changing version in `package.json` and then running `yarn` , but without running the upgrader, which also updates a number of source / config project files.